# How to use sed to modify the value in a specific column in a file with pipe-separated values

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a file with the following format :

```
#id|firstName|lastName|gender|birthday|creationDate|locationIP|browserUsed
933|Mahinda|Perera|male|19891203|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.123|Firefox
```

As you can see the delimiter is `"|"` and the fifth field is "`birthday`". I want to use sed in order to put `"-"` between the 8 digit number so as to have a result like this :

> **|1989-12-03|**

My attempt is : `sed 's/..../&-/;s/:$//' | sed 's/......./&-/;s/:$//'`

But this command makes changes in the start of each line of my file. I want to make the change in only the fifth field. Is that possible with sed?

Note that this is a homework.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original...

```
$ cat data
#id|firstName|lastName|gender|birthday|creationDate|locationIP|browserUsed
933|Mahinda|Perera|male|19891203|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.123|Firefox
```

Transforming...

```
$ cat data | sed -r 's/^(([^|]+\|){4})([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})(.+)$/\1\3-\4-\5\6/'
#id|firstName|lastName|gender|birthday|creationDate|locationIP|browserUsed
933|Mahinda|Perera|male|1989-12-03|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.123|Firefox
```

Here's some context to help you understand...

```
^                               # Start of Line
 (([^\|]+\|){4})                # Grab the first 4 fields in \1 (note \2 is not useful for us here)
 ([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}) # Split up the field we want to modify in \3, \4 and \5
 (.+)                           # Grab whatever is left in \6
$                               # End of Line
```

Comment: You don't have to escape things in character classes: `[^\|]` also excludes backslashes because they're not special here; you probably want `[^|]` instead.

Comment: That was because I did not correct output when I corrected the command. Corrected now. (removed \2)

Comment: Could you tell me why the 4th field is printed twice?

Comment: use: \1\3-\4-\5\6 instead of \1\2\3-\4-\5\6 ( \2 matches the last in the set).. I updated the regex right after I posted it. I think you might have the first one with '\2'

Comment: chksdsk - It seems you misunderstood @Benjamin W.'s comment, so I'd suggest you read it again, and make adjustments accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is certainly possible to accomplish what you want using sed, it would almost certainly be better to use awk.  The following has been tested using BSD awk, gawk, and mawk:

```
awk -F'|' '
  BEGIN {OFS=FS}
  NF==1 {print; next}
  {sub(/^....../, "&-", $5);
   sub(/^..../, "&-", $5);
   print;
  } '
```

You may wish to make the above more robust with respect to unexpected values in column 5.

If you really need to use sed, one approach would be to use `[^|]*`; for example, if your sed supports extended regular expressions:

```
sed -r 's/^(([^|]*\|){4})(....)(..)(..)/\1\3-\4-\5/'
```

Notice that `\2` is not used here.

(On a Mac, use `-E` instead of `-r`.)

Comment: Can you please write it in one line because I am using pipes?

Comment: A pipeline can be spread over multiple lines, as I have done. You can however squish the multiline program above onto one line and it will work, thanks to awk's generosity.  By the way, be aware that 'sed -r' is not universal; e.g. on a Mac you'd write 'sed -E'.

Comment: That was very helpful. Thank you.